How do I properly configure CORS for a Next.js frontend hosted on Vercel and an Express backend hosted on Render in production?
I've been struggling with a CORS issue for weeks while working on my application. Everything works fine locally, but when I test it in production, the requests from my frontend which I is hosted on Vercel to my backend that is hosted on Render are blocked by CORS.
I have tried all that is recommended for such as setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin to *, delete the deployment and redeploy etc, but nothing works
Tech Stack Frontend: Next.js hosted on Vercel Backend: Node.js/Express (hosted on Render, using JWT for access and refresh token authentication)
Problem In production, the browser blocks the requests with the following error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://ai-pulse-backend.onrender.com/api/v1/auth/login' from origin 'https://ai-pulse-frontend.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Sometimes, I also see:
CORS request did not succeed. Status code: (null)
What I've Tried:`
`I have configured CORS middleware in Express using the cors package from express js.
Allowed the Vercel domain (https://ai-pulse-frontend.vercel.app) in the CORS configuration.
Tested adding additional headers like Authorization and Content-Type on both frontend and backend.
I also Ensured withCredentials: true is used on both sides for cookies.
I also Tested API endpoints with tools like Postman (works fine).
Tried adding headers on the frontend with fetch and axios but still not working as expected.
Here is my current CORS setup in the Express backend`
import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import routes from "./routes/index";

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
 
const corsOptions = {
  origin: ["http://localhost:3000", "https://ai-pulse-frontend.vercel.app"], // Replace with your frontend URL
  credentials: true, // Allow server to accept cookies
  methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
  allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions)); // Enable CORS
app.use(express.json()); // Parse incoming JSON requests
app.use(cookieParser()); // Parse cookies


app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const origin = req.headers.origin;
  if (origin && corsOptions.origin.includes(origin)) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
  }
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");

  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.status(200).end();
    return;
  }

  next();
});


app.use(routes);

 This how I set up Axios on the frontend with withCredentials:
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "https://ai-pulse-backend.onrender.com/api/v1";

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  withCredentials: true,
});

export default api;

I also use zustand to manage authentication:
login: async (email: string, password: string) => {
  const response = await api.post("/auth/login", { email, password });
  const { accessToken } = response.data;
  api.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
}

`Questions
Are there additional headers or settings needed for JWT authentication over CORS?
Any guidance or solutions would be greatly appreciated! thank you for your help`

Your post contains several indicators that ChatGPT or another LLM was used to generate it. For a variety of reasons, the use of such generative AI tools is strictly disallowed on Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to remove and replace content that was generated using these tools.
